# table padding has no effect css

Tags: html, css

```css
#TABLE_1 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 217px;
    width: 287px;
    perspective-origin: 143.5px 108.5px;
    transform-origin: 143.5px 108.5px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
}/*#TABLE_1*/

#TBODY_2 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 217px;
    width: 287px;
    perspective-origin: 143.5px 108.5px;
    transform-origin: 143.5px 108.5px;
    border: 0px none rgb(128, 128, 128);
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
}/*#TBODY_2*/

#TR_3, #TR_7, #TR_11 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 54px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 287px;
    perspective-origin: 143.5px 27px;
    transform-origin: 143.5px 27px;
    border: 0px none rgb(128, 128, 128);
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
}/*#TR_3, #TR_7, #TR_11*/

#TD_4, #TD_8, #TD_12 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 52px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 70px;
    perspective-origin: 36px 27px;
    transform-origin: 36px 27px;
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
    padding: 0px;
}/*#TD_4, #TD_8, #TD_12*/

#TD_5, #TD_9, #TD_13 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 54px;
    perspective-origin: 35px 27px;
    transform-origin: 35px 27px;
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 1px;
}/*#TD_5, #TD_9, #TD_13*/

#TD_6, #TD_10 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 129px;
    perspective-origin: 72.5px 27px;
    transform-origin: 72.5px 27px;
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 1px;
}/*#TD_6, #TD_10*/

#TD_14 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 129px;
    perspective-origin: 72.5px 27px;
    transform-origin: 72.5px 27px;
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 1px;
}/*#TD_14*/

#TR_15 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 55px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 287px;
    perspective-origin: 143.5px 27.5px;
    transform-origin: 143.5px 27.5px;
    border: 0px none rgb(128, 128, 128);
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
}/*#TR_15*/

#TD_16 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 52px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 70px;
    perspective-origin: 36px 27.5px;
    transform-origin: 36px 27.5px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
    padding: 1px;
}/*#TD_16*/

#TD_17 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 54px;
    perspective-origin: 35px 27.5px;
    transform-origin: 35px 27.5px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 1px;
}/*#TD_17*/

#TD_18 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 129px;
    perspective-origin: 72.5px 27.5px;
    transform-origin: 72.5px 27.5px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 1px;
}/*#TD_18*/
```

```html
<table id="TABLE_1">
 <tbody id="TBODY_2">
  <tr id="TR_3">
   <td id="TD_4">
    Adult
   </td>
   <td id="TD_5">
    1
   </td>
   <td id="TD_6">
    10.00 MYR
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="TR_7">
   <td id="TD_8">
    Child
   </td>
   <td id="TD_9">
    1
   </td>
   <td id="TD_10">
    5.00 MYR
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="TR_11">
   <td id="TD_12">
    Promo
   </td>
   <td id="TD_13">
    ABC
   </td>
   <td id="TD_14">
    -5.00 MYR
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="TR_15">
   <td id="TD_16">
   </td>
   <td id="TD_17">
    Total
   </td>
   <td id="TD_18">
    -12.00 MYR
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

The table above have too much of padding, I want to reduce the height of the table by reducing the padding, but it seems no effect when I apply to it. why? I thought I already applied `border-coolapse:collapse` to the table and it will work for the padding for its `td`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all `height` and manage `padding` according to your need and you have no need to add `border-collapse: collapse;` in all `td` just add this in the `table`.

If you add `padding` or `height` in first `td` it will apply with all `td` of that parent `tr`.

```css
table{border-collapse: collapse;}
table td{padding:3px 4px} /* just for example*/
#TABLE_1 {
    
    /*height: 217px;*/
    width: 287px;
    perspective-origin: 143.5px 108.5px;
    transform-origin: 143.5px 108.5px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
}/*#TABLE_1*/

#TBODY_2 {
    
    /*height: 217px;*/
    width: 287px;
    perspective-origin: 143.5px 108.5px;
    transform-origin: 143.5px 108.5px;
    border: 0px none rgb(128, 128, 128);
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
}/*#TBODY_2*/

#TR_3, #TR_7, #TR_11 {
    
    /*height: 54px;*/
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 287px;
    perspective-origin: 143.5px 27px;
    transform-origin: 143.5px 27px;
    border: 0px none rgb(128, 128, 128);
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
}/*#TR_3, #TR_7, #TR_11*/

#TD_4, #TD_8, #TD_12 {
    
    /*height: 52px;*/
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 70px;
    perspective-origin: 36px 27px;
    transform-origin: 36px 27px;
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
    padding: 0px;
}/*#TD_4, #TD_8, #TD_12*/

#TD_5, #TD_9, #TD_13 {
    
    /*height: 24px;*/
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 54px;
    perspective-origin: 35px 27px;
    transform-origin: 35px 27px;
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
    /*padding: 15px 15px 15px 1px;*/
}/*#TD_5, #TD_9, #TD_13*/

#TD_6, #TD_10 {
    
    /*height: 24px;*/
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 129px;
    perspective-origin: 72.5px 27px;
    transform-origin: 72.5px 27px;
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
    /*padding: 15px 15px 15px 1px;*/
}/*#TD_6, #TD_10*/

#TD_14 {
    
    /*height: 24px;*/
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 129px;
    perspective-origin: 72.5px 27px;
    transform-origin: 72.5px 27px;
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
    /*padding: 15px 15px 15px 1px;*/
}/*#TD_14*/

#TR_15 {
    
    /*height: 55px;*/
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 287px;
    perspective-origin: 143.5px 27.5px;
    transform-origin: 143.5px 27.5px;
    border: 0px none rgb(128, 128, 128);
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
}/*#TR_15*/

#TD_16 {
    
    /*height: 52px;*/
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 70px;
    perspective-origin: 36px 27.5px;
    transform-origin: 36px 27.5px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
    padding: 1px;
}/*#TD_16*/

#TD_17 {
    
    /*height: 24px;*/
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 54px;
    perspective-origin: 35px 27.5px;
    transform-origin: 35px 27.5px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 1px;
}/*#TD_17*/

#TD_18 {
    
    /*height: 24px;*/
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 129px;
    perspective-origin: 72.5px 27.5px;
    transform-origin: 72.5px 27.5px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 1px;
}/*#TD_18*/
```

```html
<table id="TABLE_1">
 <tbody id="TBODY_2">
  <tr id="TR_3">
   <td id="TD_4">
    Adult
   </td>
   <td id="TD_5">
    1
   </td>
   <td id="TD_6">
    10.00 MYR
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="TR_7">
   <td id="TD_8">
    Child
   </td>
   <td id="TD_9">
    1
   </td>
   <td id="TD_10">
    5.00 MYR
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="TR_11">
   <td id="TD_12">
    Promo
   </td>
   <td id="TD_13">
    ABC
   </td>
   <td id="TD_14">
    -5.00 MYR
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="TR_15">
   <td id="TD_16">
   </td>
   <td id="TD_17">
    Total
   </td>
   <td id="TD_18">
    -12.00 MYR
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope I'll helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove heights and paddings from tr,td's individually.

```css
#TABLE_1 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 287px;
    perspective-origin: 143.5px 108.5px;
    transform-origin: 143.5px 108.5px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
}/*#TABLE_1*/

#TBODY_2 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 287px;
    perspective-origin: 143.5px 108.5px;
    transform-origin: 143.5px 108.5px;
    border: 0px none rgb(128, 128, 128);
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
}/*#TBODY_2*/

#TR_3, #TR_7, #TR_11 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 287px;
    perspective-origin: 143.5px 27px;
    transform-origin: 143.5px 27px;
    border: 0px none rgb(128, 128, 128);
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
}/*#TR_3, #TR_7, #TR_11*/

#TD_4, #TD_8, #TD_12 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 70px;
    perspective-origin: 36px 27px;
    transform-origin: 36px 27px;
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
    padding: 0px;
}/*#TD_4, #TD_8, #TD_12*/

#TD_5, #TD_9, #TD_13 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 54px;
    perspective-origin: 35px 27px;
    transform-origin: 35px 27px;
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
}/*#TD_5, #TD_9, #TD_13*/

#TD_6, #TD_10 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 129px;
    perspective-origin: 72.5px 27px;
    transform-origin: 72.5px 27px;
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
}/*#TD_6, #TD_10*/

#TD_14 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 129px;
    perspective-origin: 72.5px 27px;
    transform-origin: 72.5px 27px;
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
}/*#TD_14*/

#TR_15 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 287px;
    perspective-origin: 143.5px 27.5px;
    transform-origin: 143.5px 27.5px;
    border: 0px none rgb(128, 128, 128);
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
}/*#TR_15*/

#TD_16 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 70px;
    perspective-origin: 36px 27.5px;
    transform-origin: 36px 27.5px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
    padding: 1px;
}/*#TD_16*/

#TD_17 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 54px;
    perspective-origin: 35px 27.5px;
    transform-origin: 35px 27.5px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
}/*#TD_17*/

#TD_18 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 129px;
    perspective-origin: 72.5px 27.5px;
    transform-origin: 72.5px 27.5px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border-spacing: 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / normal Nunito, serif;
}/*#TD_18*/
```

```html
<table id="TABLE_1">
 <tbody id="TBODY_2">
  <tr id="TR_3">
   <td id="TD_4">
    Adult
   </td>
   <td id="TD_5">
    1
   </td>
   <td id="TD_6">
    10.00 MYR
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="TR_7">
   <td id="TD_8">
    Child
   </td>
   <td id="TD_9">
    1
   </td>
   <td id="TD_10">
    5.00 MYR
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="TR_11">
   <td id="TD_12">
    Promo
   </td>
   <td id="TD_13">
    ABC
   </td>
   <td id="TD_14">
    -5.00 MYR
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="TR_15">
   <td id="TD_16">
   </td>
   <td id="TD_17">
    Total
   </td>
   <td id="TD_18">
    -12.00 MYR
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the height form every td and then use padding. it will work.